# Which queue is used to execute a task when we don't specify it?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

If we don't specify a queue to execute a task, will system use main queue to execute it? More specifically, I want to know the difference between

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let image = downloadImageFromInternet()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

and

```
let image = downloadImageFromInternet() //didn't specify a queue to execute this
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.myImageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: In the second case the call to `downloadImageFromInternet` is executed on whatever the current queue is. However, most network operations will dispatch their work into some queue other than the main queue in order to ensure that the main queue is not blocked.

Comment: But downloadImageFromInternet() is obviously a blocking function. So running it on the main queue could be quite fatal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we don't specify a queue to execute a task, will system use main queue to execute it?

Not necessarily. When you say

```
let image = downloadImageFromInternet()
```

you are already on some queue. Since you don’t specify otherwise, that is the queue on which you are making the call. What queue it is depends on how this code got started. The only way code ever starts is ultimately because the runtime called it. The runtime calls your code on some queue. Unless you are told otherwise by the documentation, that will be the main queue, but always check to make sure.